# C# classes interoperate with other .NET languages

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-interface, cls

Is there a way to ensure that other .NET languages will interoperate with my C# classes  ?

Comment: Yes. It's called the CLR.

Comment: Yeah, there is no problem. Just add a reference to the compiled dll file (or to the project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important thing would be for you to use the [CLSCompliantAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.clscompliantattribute.aspx). This prevents you from inadvertently using non CLS compliant features in C#.

There are a few pretty obvious rules that I can mention here. Note, this list is not exhaustive. I just wanted to point our some of the rules to give you a feel of what CLS compliance is all about.

- Do not use unsafe types (pointers) in the public interface.
- Do not mix member name casing in the public interface.
- Do not use unsigned types in the public interface.

Read the article [Cross Language Interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/730f1wy3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, decorate your assembly with [CLSCompliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.clscompliantattribute.aspx) attribute.

[Making your code CLS Compliant](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/avmahesh/making-your-code-cls-compliant/)